# CSS3 animation only on certain pages

Tags: html, css

This is my code for CSS3 animation: shake that I applied on one of the nav links. It works like a charm, but I want it turned off when someone opens the page that it is linked to it.

How can I solve this problem?

```css
#menu-item-313 {
animation: shake 1.4s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-iteration-count: 6;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-2px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-8px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(8px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't realistically do this with CSS or HTML alone, you need to implement some kind of logic on top of all of this. It could for example be some JavaScript which based on the current URL adds a CSS class to the `body` element which disables the animation.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML and update the snippet to a working snippet so we better understand what the goal is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set a class on the body, like this, and use the `:not` selector

Sample not shaking

```css
body:not(.pg313) #menu-item-313 {
  animation: shake 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-iteration-count: 6;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-2px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-8px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(8px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="pg313">

  <div id="menu-item-313">
     Menu item 313
  </div>
  <div id="menu-item-314">
     Menu item 314
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Sample shaking

```css
body:not(.pg313) #menu-item-313 {
  animation: shake 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-iteration-count: 6;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-2px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-8px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(8px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="pg314">

  <div id="menu-item-313">
     Menu item 313
  </div>
  <div id="menu-item-314">
     Menu item 314
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent, works! Thank you!

ps. If you put the class inside the "()", then it will work only on that page which is strange because the syntax says:

body :not(#blabla) - so you would expect it not to work only on that page, but it works only there, if you know what I mean haha.