# show div menu on load page

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have this function where it shows divs when a link is clicked. Works great, but i want this to be a menu. Once the div is shown, it has links to another page. Which again works fine, but once the page is loaded i want the div still displayed, with the current menu list. It gets hidden when a new page has loaded. This is the code i have cobbled together. any ideas?

```js
$('#menu a').click(function(e){
  hideContentDivs();
  var tmp_div = $(this).attr('id');

  ($('.somthing').find('.'+tmp_div)).show();
});

function hideContentDivs(){
  $('.somthing div').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
```

```css
#menu ul {
  list-style-image: url('socialicons/webicon-aboutme.png');
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.somthing{
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">Marine Vinyls</span></p>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="javascript:void(0)"id="CTP_Marine_Vinyls"><span class="text-link-text-1">CTP Marine Vinyls</span></a>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="javascript:void(0)"id="Nautolex_Vinyls"><span class="text-link-text-1">Nautolex Vinyls</span></a>
    <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">Fabrics</span></p>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="javascript:void(0)"id="AGUA"><span class="text-link-text-1">AGUA</span></a>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="javascript:void(0)"id="CoverTex"><span class="text-link-text-1">CoverTex</span></a>
    <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">Acrylics</span></p>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="javascript:void(0)"id="TopGun"><span class="text-link-text-1">Topgun</span></a>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="javascript:void(0)"id="Odyssey"><span class="text-link-text-1">Odyssey</span></a>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="javascript:void(0)" id="Acrylic_Canvas"><span class="text-link-text-1">Acrylic Canvas</span></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="somthing">
  <div class="CTP_Marine_Vinyls" class="content">
    <br>
    <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">CTP_Marine_Vinyls</span></p>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#" id="CTP_Marine_Vinyls"><span class="text-link-text-1">Zander</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="Nautolex_Vinyls" class="content">
    <br>
    <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">Nautolex_Vinyls</span></p>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#" id="Acrylic_Canvas"><span class="text-link-text-1">Acrylic Canvas</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="AGUA" class="content">
    <br> 
    <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">AGUA</span></p>
    <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="../../material_pages/Agua_Range/Vistas_Collection.php" id="Acrylic_Canvas"><span class="text-link-text-1">Vistas_Collection</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Class attribute needs to be like this `<div class="Nautolex_Vinyls content">`

Comment: check iframes , load each pages in new iframes . That way you can retain the links menu and show the pages in sideways.

Comment: use this https://jsfiddle.net/ptfp4jjx/

Comment: thanks for the reply! sadly my knowledge is lacking here. to have the class (class "Nautolex_Vinyls content") is just being efficient? not fixing the above issue? iframe is a great idea!

for iframe im using this method

<iframe name='playframe' src='http://path/to/playlist/1'></iframe>
<a href='http://path/to/playlist/1' target='playframe'>Playlist 1</a>​
<a href='http://path/to/playlist/2' target='playframe'>Playlist 2</a>

Comment: About `class="Nautolex_Vinyls content"`, it is not about efficiency, you should only use an attribute once within a tag, not as in your case, twice, as that is invalid. .. But that fix does likely not solved your question though, so before even start look for functionality error, one need to at least have it coded properly, which yours isn't, so I suggest you do that first and then update your question. ... About your question, check this answer of mine, it hopefully will give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36088376/2827823